# White rectangle appearing below <embed> tag

Tags: bootstrap-4, removing-whitespace

When I'm trying to embed another webpage to my main webpage, a white rectangle appears below it.

[image: White rectangle below <embed> tag]

Here's the embed code I'm using:

```
<embed class="blogpost darkable" src="Blogpost_0001.html" width="500px" height="700px"></embed>
```

Here's the webpage I'm trying to embed:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="..." />
        <link href="site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <title>Blogpost 0001</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="blog-post darkable">
            ...
        </div>

        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

EDIT: The main webpage is [here](https://hastebin.com/uzatavitaz.xml), and the webpage I'm trying to embed is [here](https://hastebin.com/abuqoragix.xml). Site.css can be found [here](https://hastebin.com/piqorazohe.css).

Comment: Can you provide a URL to the site?

Comment: @pjones235 It's not published, but I can provide links to the source code